# .htaccess convert _ to - from all url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Orignal URL:**  `/icon/line-vector-icons-1-2/chatting_bubble-_talk-_comments-_chat-_online_conversation-62`

**Wanted URL:** `/icon/line-vector-icons-1-2/chatting-bubble-talk-comments-chat-online-conversation-62`

"`_`" and "`-_`" OR "`_-`" should be like `-` 
Please let me know if my question is already answered somewhere else, and please feel free to edit and correct my question.

the question is somehow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650542/in-htaccess-id-like-to-replace-underscores-with-hyphens-and-then-redirect-the) question but it doesn't meet my requirement or may be i am doing something wrong this is my .htaccess I'm using. Please let me know if something is wrong with it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /icooons/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N]
```

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650542/in-htaccess-id-like-to-replace-underscores-with-hyphens-and-then-redirect-the)?

Comment: I'm sorry, i tried it but doesn't seem like working.. can you help me out what I'm doing wrong? I do not want to redirect url, i just want to convert  "`_`" , "`_-`" ,"`-_`". the solution is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this recursive rule (see my inline comments):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /icon/

# keep replacing underscores to hyphen until there is no _ (use internal rewrite)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:_-?|-_)(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=USCORE:1,DPI]

# when there is no underscore make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:USCORE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)$ $1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks is there a way to not to redirect? i mean i just want to convert it or simply hide it, not redirect it, if i do that whole page will be like 404 not found.

Comment: What do you mean by hiding? Once `_-` has been converted to `-` no code can get `_-` back in URL since it may be originally `_` or `_-` or `-_`. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I mean let say my real page is test_1 using your code will make it test-1. is it possible that browser treat it like test_1 but in address bar it looks like test-1, this way my page will not go 404..

Comment: Browser sees what URL is shown. Using another rule or code `test-1` can be converted to `test_1`. But problem is if original URL has mix of `_` and `-` and URL looks like `test-1_2_3` then after conversion it will become `test-1-2-3`. Now problem is how to convert it back to `test-1_2_3` internally since replacing `-` by `_`  will make it `test_1_2_3` which is not correct.

Comment: +1 Thank you I understand. i wish i could find a solution to my problem but seems like it is impossible as url keeps changing and their also is no way to store url in variable or session and then use it.. Thanks for your help.